# Plugins to add features to java

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, project

I'm working on a project that requires to add some features to an existing java application using Netbeans. After searching the net, i founded that I should use "plugins". I didn't hear of plugins before. 
I have a java application that I should download it from the net, then lets say I have to add a button, when clicked, calls a function that is written in some class in the application. In other words I want to make a new class that is able to access the classes and functions that are written in this application.

What I understood from searching the net is that:
-In the downloaded project's folder there is a folder named plugins.
-This folder contains zip files that contains classes and other stuff.
-I should make a plugin and add it to this folder in order to add a specific feature to the application.

That's what I know, if there is something wrong in what I said, I'll be thankful to correct to me.

Now, my question is that I want a link or website that can teach me how to create and add a plugin to an existing java application. Thank you :)

Comment: _"I want a link or website that can teach me how to create and add a plugin to an existing java application"_ => Voting to close since this question is off topic for Stack Overflow: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on the java application you're talking about. Not every application has a Plugins functionality. And not every Java Application uses the same Plugin API. The best bet is to go to the site of the App you're talking about and see if they offer a documentation about their Plugin API.